# How can I return a value from a thread without using the future header?

Tags: c++, multithreading

My current compiler doesn't support the future header, and I'm unable to update it as on Android, the compiler is wrapped in an app. Because of this, I decided to try to make my own simple future class.
I have most of it laid out, but can't figure out how to get the return value from the thread (as this seems to be beyond its intended use). 
I could pass my future class a functor that contains it's own return holder variable to be retrieved later, but that's a little limiting, because anything I wanted to pass it would have to be derived from the original functors class, and not just a function.

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm assuming the standard future header doesn't use black magic to do it. Does it use a "different version" of threads that allow it to receive a value back?

(It's not so old as to not be compatible with threading, it just has issues with the future header for some reason)

Thanks

Comment: Does your compiler even support `std::thread`? Probably informative so as to determine just how far back in time we're going.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes it does. It's actually a fairly new version (4.8.2), but I get the error "... error: variable 'std::future<long int> fut' has initializer but incomplete type future <long > fut = async (factorial, 100000);" I looked it up, and apparently the odd version of gcc has issues with the future header. I've emailed the dev, but I decided to work on this in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by writing your own simple Future class you're on the right way. 
What does your code look like?

I'm not sure if I fully understand your statement:

> I could pass my future class a functor that contains it's own return holder variable to be retrieved later, but that's a little limiting, because anything I wanted to pass it would have to be derived from the original functors class, and not just a function.

I wouldn't pass a functor but only store variables for the values I want as return values from the thread. If you want different return values you could derive classes from your SimpleFuture class.

Comment: The functors idea was something I though of on the spot, and isn't technically a functor. The original idea was to have a object that could store the result from the threaded function, and could be retrieved with a function later. The problem with that is 1, you couldn't just pass it a function, it would have to be a pre-made class that you would derive from and place whatever task you had inside of it (basically acting as a wrapper), and at the end of the function, you would have to manually add code store the result of the function. I looked at it in my head, and it looked messy.

Comment: I don't see why this would become messy. Maybe if you still need help you could edit your post to provide more detail. Otherwise I'm afraid you won't get more help